# Ubuntu router setup guide iptables rules

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, iptables

I'm trying to figure out the meaning of the `iptables` rules in the [Official Guide for Setting up a Ubuntu Router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router). For example, `*nat`. I can not find anywhere on the internet that has `*nat` for `iptables`.

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT
```

Comment: Good question. The same goes for `*filter`. The [man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) makes no mention of `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it to be the selector for the name of the table. The `*` is used in place of the `-t` option for the command line variant of the command, with selects the table. For example, normally the table would be selected by specifying `-t <tablename>`, so in this case `-t nat`, to select the *nat* table:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

The example that you have provided is using input redirection from a *[here document](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)* to `iptables-restore` - note the `<<EOF ... EOF` and so instead of the command line option (`-t`), individual lines are used instead, like so:

```
iptables-restore <<-EOF
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
EOF
```

One could argue that as `-A` is still in the here document, why is `-t` not? I don't know the answer to that, hopefully someone else does.

Likewise after the `*nat` table has been `COMMIT`ed, then the `*filter` table is selected, worked upon and then `COMMIT`ed.

```
iptables-restore <<-EOF
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT
EOF
```

If you are looking for a tutorial, you may find this [NAT - Network Address Translation](http://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial) tutorial useful.